# Is a grid-like network more efficient than a random network?

Tags: optimization, stochastic-processes, graph-theory, networks

Imagine two different types of street networks with the same number of nodes and where edges are weighted according to their length. Both network types cover the same geographic area (say 1km²) and have the same node density. The first type is a grid, where every street goes in one of two possible, perpendicular directions and where every street is the same length (network (a) below). The other type corresponds to more random networks, where streets don't follow a particular order, their length and their directions varying randomly ((b) and (c), for instance). In each network, you have eight points of departure/arrival, labelled A to H. You measure the average shortest path distance from every point to every other point. Would the grid network have shorter shortest paths on average?

Intuitively, I would assume not. I would say that the grid network would have less variable shortest paths, since you don't risk a big detour, but you are also unlikely to find a shortcut. However, I was looking to see if there are any reasons why a regular network might be more efficient than a more random one.

[image: Network examples]

Comment: Does the network include the edges along the bounding rectangle?

Comment: No, just the blue lines (it's hard to distinguish, I know), so none of the edges of the rectangle.

Comment: If you build shortcuts--even between existing nodes--the trips will get shorter ;-).  What, then, are the restrictions on this network?  Is it perhaps that it must be limited to 12 straight segments?  Anything else?

Comment: The restriction on the grid network is that it is made up of perpendicular and equally spaced segments. The random network must contain 12 straight edges, and the lettered nodes must stay in the same place as in the grid network. In short, the only thing you're changing in the random network is the location of the four central nodes.